# Issue IOS simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I upgraded VS 2015 CE with Update 2 by installing Xamarin, but I have a problem with IOS simulators, because after you successfully connected the Mac Agent, the list of available devices (iPhoneSimulator) remains empty. The operating system (Mac) installed on a VM's OS X El capitan 10.11.4. I tried to start the test project by Xamarin studio on Mac and it all works. Both versions of Xamrain (Pc and Mac) are updated to the latest version. How do I fix it? Thank you

Edit based on comments:

@Milev Pavlov Yes, XCode version is 7.3(7D175) @Alan Clark Yes I have Mac OS X in a VM. The version info:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA395 Microsoft Visual Basic 2015
>
> Visual C# 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA395 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015 00322-20000-00000-AA395 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU 00322-20000-00000-AA395 Windows Phone SDK
>   8.0 - ENU
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package 5.2.60328.3
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1) 14.1.20203.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2 4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013 5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit
>
> Azure App Service Tools v2.8.2 14.0.20201.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v2.8.2
>
> Clang with Microsoft CodeGen 14.0.25115 Clang with Microsoft CodeGen
>
> Common Azure Tools 1.7 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> DataFactoryProject 1.0 Microsoft Data Factory Package
>
> GitHub.VisualStudio 1.0 A Visual Studio Extension that brings the
>   GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
>
> JavaScript Language Service 2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System 2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> KofePackagePackage Extension 1.0 KofePackagePackage Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> Microsoft Azure Data Factory Node Node 1.0 Azure Data Factory
>   extension for Visual Studio Server Explorer.
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service 2.0.2900.0 Language service for
>   Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio 2.0.2900.0 An
>   integrated development environment for HDInsight application
>   development.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools 1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools 2.8 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2015 - v2.8.40211.2
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger 1.0 Provides support for connecting Visual
>   Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> NuGet Package Manager 3.4.1 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer 1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio extension
>   to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics
>   product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.60311.1 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript 1.8.29.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)
>   14.0.25116.00 Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)
>
> Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (iOS) 14.0.25116.00
>   Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (iOS)
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova Update 8 Visual Studio Tools
>   for Apache Cordova
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps 14.0.25123.00 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> Xamarin 4.0.3.214 (0dd817c) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android 6.0.3.5 (a94a03b) Visual Studio plugin to enable
>   development for Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.iOS 9.6.1.8 (3a25bf1) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Check your XCode version (needs to be 7+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac, open a terminal and enter:

ps -eax | grep Xamarin

Then

kill 12345
Where 12345 is replaced by the pid of the process "IDB".

Then wait a few seconds. 
If the list of emulators still does not display try again this trick.

If it still does not display :
close vs, 
make sure there is no process listed on the Mac by the above command, kill them if needed. 
Restart vs. 
should be ok.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. I hope that the problem will be solved in future releases and that this is only a temporary workaround.

Comment: I didn't see anything called IDB but I found a process called "csproxy" that when I killed and restarted Xamarin, the simulators came back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind remote simulator is only available on enterprise

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

```
Remoted iOS Simulator requires a Visual Studio Enterprise license
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you suggesting that you have Mac OS X running in a VM?  The only supported scenario is running a Windows VM within OS X, where Windows would be the virtualised environment.  If this is how you do have your computer set up then please confirm your version information for both the Mac and PC, along with your Xamarin logs:

Version info:

Visual Studio
Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info [button]

Xamarin Studio in OS X
Xamarin Studio -> About Xamarin Studio -> Show Details -> Copy Information [button]

Logs:

In Visual Studio:
Help -> Xamarin -> Zip Logs

Xamarin for Mac logs:
You can select the "Go -> Go to Folder" menu item in Finder, and then copy and paste the path into the dialog.

~/Library/Logs/Xamarin-[MAJOR.MINOR]

Comment: FYI: We run dozens of OS-X Virtual Machines on Mac Pros to share with our Windows-based Xamarin devs. In terms of `officially supported` By MS/X that is a different question but they work fine and are supported by Apple

Comment: @SushiHangover That set up would be fine and within the confines of the Apple licence agreement, but it's not a setup we recommend for Xamarin since we tend to gravitate towards running a Windows VM from within OS X on a Mac.  This, alongside running two physical machines, are the methods we support.  However, if your method works for you then great :)